# QFileDialog in a non-QT app

Tags: qt, qwidget, qfiledialog

I have an app that uses a 3rd party GUI framework, but I want to open files with using QFileDialog. I'm thinking of instantiating a subclass of QWidget that is invisible and serves the purpose of serving up the dialog.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need for an invisible widget, since the file dialog doesn't require a a parent widget in order to be shown up.

Since the dialog needs to have a Qt event loop running, you will need to either show the dialog modally using `exec()`, or using one of the static functions like `getOpenFileName`.

To use any of the widget classes, including the file dialog, you need to have an instance of `QApplication`, although that instance doesn't have to have its `exec()` method called.

Comment: are you sure QFileDialog::getOpenFileName requires no instance of QApplication? I keep getting segfaults.

Comment: @ejang I'd have hoped that the last paragraph is explicit enough: you *do* need a `QApplication` instance.

Comment: thanks, instantiating a QApplication right before callign QFileDialog worked. Evidently QFileDialog is doing something in the background that made this possible even when the exec loop was not called.

Comment: @ejang It's doing nothing in the background. It runs an event loop, and it's very much in the foreground and block all other processing in the thread where you invoke it. As I've said, the dialog needs to have the event loop running. This can be accomplished by either calling any of its static functions, or by using `exec()` on the dialog itself. In other words: if you call a static function, you are spinning an event loop.